# why My application is getting The ConnectionString property has not been initialized error daily?

Tags: windows, iis, connection-string, windows-server-2012, iis-8

I am using IIS 8.0 and windows server 2012. My application is going down daily and displaying that error. After I restarted the IIS it is working fine. Why it is behaving like that ?

Comment: Any chance you can provide some more information like what's the error message, is it happening at a specific time, what is the load on the server like, can you re-create the issue ... etc?

Comment: Server Error in '/App' Application. 
The ConnectionString property has not been initialized. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
This is the actual Error I am getting. Load on server is nearly 500 users /daily.